# Change default behaviour of radio buttons and check boxes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Hoping someone can advise me on this

Consider the following, which lets the user picks who they think will win a match

[image]

In this image Top match is game 1 in the round bottom match is game 2 in round etc...

Matches/fixtures gets pulled from a database and in a php loop fixtures gets dynamically displayed.

My problem is this:

**The element name attribute must be set to pick[]**

Now when  I use radiobuttons the following happens

[image]

[image]

**So user can only select 1 match in the group of matches...not very good**

When a change it to textbox, this happens:

[image]

[image]
User can select more than 1 winner for a match...also not very good

There is nothing strange about this since this is the **default behaviour** of checkboxes and radio buttons, however I am hoping someone can advise me if it is possible to modify this default behaviour, to do the following:

1. -For each match only one winner/result can be chosen
2. -However a round has many matches so a result for more than one match can be selected

ANY advise tremendously appreciated

Comment: It would be a great advantage for you question, if you'd provide a running demo of what you have.

Comment: @NicoO, whith due respect, I fail to see how my explanation is not sufficient

Comment: I don't say it's not sufficient, it's a good question. It's just way more easy to answer with a given demo i think. Without your code the answering person  needs to come up with something completely new and can not just edit the relevant part. Best of luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just give your arrays an index (incremental) for each group then it will still be posted as `picks[]`:

```html
<input type="radio" name="picks[0]" value="Southampton" />
<input type="radio" name="picks[0]" value="West Ham" />
<input type="radio" name="picks[0]" value="Draw" />
<br />
<input type="radio" name="picks[1]" value="Everton" />
<input type="radio" name="picks[1]" value="Arsenal" />
<input type="radio" name="picks[1]" value="Draw" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Each radio group needs a unique "name" value.

```
<input type="radio" name="picks1[]" value="Team 1" /> Team 1
<input type="radio" name="picks1[]" value="Team 2" /> Team 2
<input type="radio" name="picks1[]" value="Team 3" /> Team 3

<input type="radio" name="picks2[]" value="Team 1" /> Team 1
<input type="radio" name="picks2[]" value="Team 2" /> Team 2
<input type="radio" name="picks3[]" value="Team 3" /> Team 3
```

**JSFIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/b1paqknj/